# How to have subfooter in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I used the data-role="footer" but I want 2 links below that blue bar to also be part of the footer.

```
<div data-role="footer" class="footer" id="ftrMain" name="ftrMain" data-position="fixed">
    &copy; 2011 Probity Investigations
</div>
<div data-role="footer" id="subfooter" name="subfooter" >
    <div style="float: left;">
        <a href="../../agents/index.php" rel="external">Full Site</a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <a href="logout.php" rel="external">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I want to fix it to bottom. I tried creating the second footer with data-theme="c" but it doesnt quite match.

Basically like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfl6g.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly like the picture but maybe you could play with it.

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gN5Fy/20/

Documentation on navbars: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Comment: Is it possible to do buttons on left and right like you can in header?

Comment: Best try: http://jsfiddle.net/gN5Fy/45/ can't get text to align in the center, div throws off the display

Answer (score 0):

This finally fixed it:

```
<div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
<a href="../../agents/index.php" rel="external" data-role="button">Full Site</a>
<a style="float:right; margin-right:25px;" href="logout.php" rel="external" data-role="button">Logout</a>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 230px; bottom: 30px; position: relative;">&copy; 2011 Probity Investigations</div>
</div>
```